# How to insert an element within a form using velo

Tags: jquery, velo

I am trying to insert an element within a form on Wix. When a user clicks on an option from the dropdown menu asking "how many items would you like to sell?", multiple small forms appear depending on that number the user chooses. Here's an example from stereobuyers.com:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I've done so far, group 1 is the equipment form, quote dropdown is the dropdown list. Right now it just shows without it getting in between two input fields, which is what I'm expecting.

```
    $w("#group1").hide();

    $w("#quoteDropdown").onChange((event) => {
        let newValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(Number(newValue))
        let quantity = Number(newValue);

        // if the quantity is more than 1 show the equipment form
        if(quantity > 0) {
            $w("#group1").show()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll want to put the equipment form in a repeater. Then you can add as many of them as you need by resizing the repeater.

You resize the repeater by setting its `data` property. Here, you're not going to actually pass any data, but you can use the size of the data array to add or remove equipment forms based on the number of items to sell.

For example, if the number of items to sell is three, you can set the repeater data like this and you will have three equipment forms:

```
$w('#equipmentRepeater').data = [{_id: '0'},{_id: '1'},{_id: '2'}];
```

Then, of course, you have to get the information out of the forms, probably into a collection. You can do that with a dataset or the Data API. It will be a little trickier than normal because you have a form in a repeater.